# Snake Game for Raspberry Pi Sense HAT written in Python

Tags: python, beginner, game, snake-game, raspberry-pi

## Goals

- learn Python
- improve problem-solving skills
- improve my coding style

## Hardware

This code runs on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (Raspbian OS) in combination with the Sense HAT. The 8x8 LED-Matrix on the Sense HAT is used for displaying the game-graphics and the included joystick is used for steering the snake. While developing the game, following online-tool has been used to emulate the hardware: https://trinket.io/sense-hat
(NOTE: after clicking on the simulation, the arrow keys on the keyboard can be used for generating the joystick movement)

## Code

```py
    from sense_hat import SenseHat
    import time
    import random
    
    senseHat = SenseHat()
    senseHat.low_light = True
    
    GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    START_DELAY = 3
    MATRIX_MIN_VALUE = 0
    MATRIX_MAX_VALUE = 7
    MATRIX_SIZE = 8
    
    while True:
        # variables:
        gameOverFlag = False
        growSnakeFlag = False
        generateRandomFoodFlag = False
        snakeMovementDelay = 0.5
        snakeMovementDelayDecrease = -0.02
    
        # start delay:
        time.sleep(START_DELAY)
    
        # set default snake starting position (values are chosen by preference):
        snakePosX = [3]
        snakePosY = [6]
    
        # generate random food position:
        while True:
            foodPosX = random.randint(0, 7)
            foodPosY = random.randint(0, 7)
            if foodPosX != snakePosX[0] or foodPosY != snakePosY[0]:
                break
    
        # set default snake starting direction (values are chosen by preference):
        movementX = 0
        movementY = -1
    
        # -----------------------------------
        #             game loop
        # -----------------------------------
        while not gameOverFlag:
            # check if snake eats food:
            if foodPosX == snakePosX[0] and foodPosY == snakePosY[0]:
                growSnakeFlag = True
                generateRandomFoodFlag = True
                snakeMovementDelay += snakeMovementDelayDecrease
    
            # check if snake bites itself:
            for i in range(1, len(snakePosX)):
                if snakePosX[i] == snakePosX[0] and snakePosY[i] == snakePosY[0]:
                    gameOverFlag = True
    
            # check if game-over:
            if gameOverFlag:
                break
    
            # check joystick events:
            events = senseHat.stick.get_events()
            for event in events:
                if event.direction == "left" and movementX != 1:
                    movementX = -1
                    movementY = 0
                elif event.direction == "right" and movementX != -1:
                    movementX = 1
                    movementY = 0
                elif event.direction == "up" and movementY != 1:
                    movementY = -1
                    movementX = 0
                elif event.direction == "down" and movementY != -1:
                    movementY = 1
                    movementX = 0
    
            # grow snake:
            if growSnakeFlag:
                growSnakeFlag = False
                snakePosX.append(0)
                snakePosY.append(0)
    
            # move snake:
            for i in range((len(snakePosX) - 1), 0, -1):
                snakePosX[i] = snakePosX[i - 1]
                snakePosY[i] = snakePosY[i - 1]
    
            snakePosX[0] += movementX
            snakePosY[0] += movementY
    
            # check game borders:
            if snakePosX[0] > MATRIX_MAX_VALUE:
                snakePosX[0] -= MATRIX_SIZE
            elif snakePosX[0] < MATRIX_MIN_VALUE:
                snakePosX[0] += MATRIX_SIZE
            if snakePosY[0] > MATRIX_MAX_VALUE:
                snakePosY[0] -= MATRIX_SIZE
            elif snakePosY[0] < MATRIX_MIN_VALUE:
                snakePosY[0] += MATRIX_SIZE
    
            # spawn random food:
            if generateRandomFoodFlag:
                generateRandomFoodFlag = False
                retryFlag = True
                while retryFlag:
                    foodPosX = random.randint(0, 7)
                    foodPosY = random.randint(0, 7)
                    retryFlag = False
                    for x, y in zip(snakePosX, snakePosY):
                        if x == foodPosX and y == foodPosY:
                            retryFlag = True
                            break
    
            # update matrix:
            senseHat.clear()
            senseHat.set_pixel(foodPosX, foodPosY, RED)
            for x, y in zip(snakePosX, snakePosY):
                senseHat.set_pixel(x, y, GREEN)
    
            # snake speed (game loop delay):
            time.sleep(snakeMovementDelay)
```

## Questions

- Would this example be better implemented in an object-oriented or procedural manner?
- Am I thinking too C/C++-like when implementing e.g. the for-loops?
- Would code like this ever be accepted in an "professional environment"?
- What can be improved and learned?